# how to solve $t(t−\sin t)^{5/3}=0.6\pi$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, roots, newton-raphson

How to solve this question? Using the Newton method? I have tried using this approximation, $\sin t ≈ 120(\pi−t)t/\pi^5$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a numerical procedure,  define
$$
f(t) = t(t-\sin t)^{5/3} -2\pi/5
$$
and differentiate to find $f'(t)$. Then define the Newton recurrence relationship by
$$
t_{n+1} = t_n - \frac{f(t_n)}{f'(t_n},
$$
plug in $f$ and $f'$ and simplify.

Can you pick a good initial guess $t_0$?

Comment: i dont know how to pick a initial guess since a bad starting point will cause the newton recurrence to go horribly wrong.

Comment: @ChunChoeNg play with a couple, you can see by eye that $f(0) < 0$ but $f(\pi) > 0$, play with something around $t_0=1$ and see where the first couple of terms take you

Answer (score -1):

What, exactly, is the question?  If it is just to solve $\theta\left(\theta- sin(\theta)\right)^{5/3}= 0$, the first thing I would do is to note that $\theta= 0$ is certainly a root.  If $\theta \ne 0$ then we must have $\theta- sin(\theta)= 0$.  To use 
"Newton's method", we have $f(\theta)= \theta- sin(\theta)$ so $f'(\theta)= 1- cos(\theta)$.  Newton's method requires that we choose some starting value, $\theta_0$, then iteratively calculate $x_{n+1}- \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}= \frac{\theta- sin(\theta)}{1- cos(\theta)}$.  I don't see why you would use a quadratic approximation.  In fact a graph quickly shows that x= 0 is the **only** root to the equation.

Comment: I think RHS is $0.6\pi = 2\pi/5$ not $0$...